# How to take information from text on a website and transfer into string variable in C#

Tags: c#, html, .net

I'm trying to pull the price text from [this](https://shop.tcgplayer.com/productcatalog/product/show?newSearch=false&ProductType=All&IsProductNameExact=false&ProductName=mountain) for example, and insert it into a string variable in my project. I know from my Java friends that something along the lines of BufferedReader would do it, but I don't know what that means in Java, or what I would need in  C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Options for HTML Scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/)?

Comment: Tip: You need to try before asking. Try to write some code, and then you ask.

Comment: thing is, i dont even know how to start it...

Comment: Ask your Java friends to work it out with you in pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to try [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) package. You can install it with Nuget. It uses jQuery syntax to query html elements.

See example:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var pageHtml = client.DownloadString("https://shop.tcgplayer.com/...");
    var page = new CQ(pageHtml);
    var priceText = page.Find("dl.product__market-price > dd").Text().Trim();
}
```